# Windows 7 full window transparency

Tags: windows-7, desktop

How can I configure (preferably using Aero) transparancy for a window.

For the sake of example, I would like the calculator to be transparant & always on top of other windows.

I have this feature in Linux with Gnome "On Top" & metacity transparency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe **[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)** is for you

**Features:**

> Automatically maximize or minimize or
>   normal all new windows you specify.
>
> Automatically minimize all new windows
>   you specify to system tray.
>
> **Automatically keep all new windows you specify always on top.**
>
> Adds several menu items to standard
>   window system menu.
>
> Minimize the current window to system
>   tray.
>
> **Apply transparency effect from 0% (fully transparent) to 100% (solid)
>   rate to any program in Windows
>   2000/XP/2003/Vista.**
>
> Show window property of application,
>   such as window handle, class name,
>   process id etc.
>
> Auto Refresh Internet explorer at
>   custom intervals.

p.s.: Auto Window Manager works with Windows 7

Screenshot of Windows 7 with AWM:

[image: transparent calculator on top of the active window]

Comment: +1 - Looks like a great solution to what Maxim Veksler is looking for.